# VIM folding for large log files

Tags: vim

i have a log file that i want to be able to fold depending on the number of "*".
my log looks something like this:
i have tried working with vim's fold functions but i cant' get them to work exactly how i want to. i must be doing something wrong here.

```
*** high level command
** mid level
* low level
*low level
** mid level
more of the same...
*** high level
and so on...
```

how do i get vim to fold the code  and determining the fold level depending on the number of *s?
thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand how you want this to work, but you might try something like this:

```
function! MyFoldLevel(lnum)
    return 4 - strlen(matchstr(getline(a:lnum), '\m^\**'))
endfunction

setlocal foldexpr=MyFoldLevel(v:lnum)
setlocal foldmethod=expr        
setlocal foldlevel=0            
setlocal foldcolumn=4           
setlocal foldenable
```

Write the above to a file and source it when you edit the logs.